# Exchange 2007 - Message Tracking Logs - Undelivered Email

Tags: exchange

I am administering an Exchange 2007 server with around 15user mailboxes.
One user is having trouble receiving emails from an email address outside the organisation.

I've run the message tracking tool with EVENTID as 'Receive' and can see this particular sender email address  in the results.

If i run the same tracking search with EVENTID as 'DELIVER' - The emails do not show up.Therefore I can see the email is getting to the exchange server, but NOT delivering to the mailbox.

I've heard I should disable IPV6 if its not in use as this can cause problems, is there any truth to that?

Comment: I should add, I've also searched my AV quarantine folder. Nothing appears as being blocked/deleted from that senders address!

Answer (score 2):

For such a small number of users, I'd probably run the message tracking around the time the message was sent and see all the activity around that message and not just the RECEIVE and DELIVER events. If it's not being delivered to the mailbox, you might see some deferred messages or NDRs going back. You might also have some odd configuration issue which results in Exchange not thinking this message is for any of your users and forwarding it on to another SMTP server.

My initial reaction would be to check the user is not over quota. If that's no good I'd have a look at transport rules to see if you've got something crazy which bounces particular messages, or maybe the built in anti-spam agents are rejecting the message.

As for disabling IPv6, I really wouldn't do that. [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629624%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx) says there's no need to disable it, and I really can't think of any reason to *ever* disable it these days.

> Exchange servers fully support IPv6 networks, and there is no need to disable IPv6 on your Exchange servers.